# Verilog ** Notation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What does ** mean in verilog?

I have the following logic provided for a testbench

```
localparam NUM_INPUT_BITS       = 1;
localparam NUM_OUTPUT_BITS      = NUM_INPUT_BITS + 1;
localparam MAX_OUTPUT_BIT       = NUM_OUTPUT_BITS - 1;
localparam NUM_TEST_BITS        = (NUM_INPUT_BITS * 2) + 1;
localparam MAX_TEST_BIT         = NUM_TEST_BITS - 1;
localparam NUM_TEST_CASES       = 2 ** NUM_TEST_BITS;
localparam MAX_TEST_VALUE       = NUM_TEST_CASES - 1;
localparam TEST_A_BITTEST_A_BIT = 0;
localparam TEST_B_BIT           = NUM_INPUT_BITS;
localparam TEST_CARRY_IN_BIT    = MAX_TEST_BIT;
localparam TEST_SUM_BIT         = 0;
localparam TEST_CARRY_OUT_BIT   = MAX_OUTPUT_BIT;
localparam TEST_DELAY           = 10;
```

And I cannot figure out what the NUM_TEST_CASES value will evaluate to.  The final answer should be 8, so I'm assumming ** means y ** x = y^x, but I want to confirm.

Comment: Link to the IEEE Std 1800-2012: http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf

Comment: ^ was taken for the XOR operator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Double asterisk is a "power" operator introduced in Verilog 2001. It is an arithmetic operator that takes left hand side operand to the power of right hand side operand. In other words, `X ** Y` raises `X` to the power of `Y`. So in your case `2 ** NUM_TEST_BITS` means 2 to the power of `NUM_TEST_BITS`.

Comment: what is the operator if i am using verilog 1993?

Comment: @pavansp: For the special case where the base is 2 you could use shift operator: `1 << NUM_BITS`. That is not what you have asked but since all examples here use base 2 this might be one special case solution.

Answer (score 2):

** is power operation(raised to the power of).

Comment: There's very little point in rehashing what's already been said in another answer, especially if that answer has already been around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Often `2 ** N-1` is used to indicate all `N` bits are 1. For example `2 ** 4 - 1 = 15` means `4'b1111`.